# How do you override the meta deta to create multiple unique share links on a single Wordpress post?

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, metadata, social-networking

Typically when you create social share links within a page, Facebook/Twitter pull the meta deta from the og tags to create the thumbnail; however, I am displaying a newsletter on a single page with multiple unique stories. I'd like each individual story to be shareable with a unique title and description, but I can't figure out how to give each share button a unique title and description.

I've attached a single Facebook share link below. As you can see I have it linked to the ID #top-story, so it will load the page at that story. I want the title and description of that story to be in the thumbnail though, not the meta data from the overall page.

```
<a class="link" title="Facebook" href=http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=
[insert_php]the_permalink();[/insert_php]#top-story&amp;t=
[insert_php]the_title();[/insert_php]" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
```

EDIT: I don't think I explained in the best possible way, but believe this example would help. The link below accomplishes what I am trying to replicate.

http://theskimm.com/2017/06/22/skimm-for-june-23rd-4

Comment: This is a bit unclear. Please clarify your question

Comment: Each story should be a WP post (or of a custom post type). Use those links on your newsletter page to direct users to said post.

Comment: I apologize, it's slightly confusing to explain I admit. I think it's easiest to give an example. The link below you see is a newsletter with several stories in a single page- yet each story has a unique share link. I want to replicate this as closely as possible. Currently when I share any link on the page, it creates a thumbnail using the overall page meta data, not the unique story. I want to override that for each story.

http://theskimm.com/2017/06/22/skimm-for-june-23rd-4

Comment: @HalfCrazed I'm fully aware how to do what you recommended, but for the solution I am trying to create, I am displaying a newsletter with several stories in a single post. The example I used above accomplishes this, but I am stumped in trying to replicate it.

Comment: Ok, misunderstood. Posting answer.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is this (in fact, this is how theskimm does it):

1. Generate a "slug" for each article, probably based on the title then use this as an anchor for the article section (eg: `<a name="slug-of-article"></a>`)
2. Link to the newsletter page as usual, but pass a query string such as `?jumpto=slug-of-article`
3. Write a javascript handler that checks the `jumpto` query string parameter, and if it exists, scroll to that ID

You can see this working from theskimm here: 
[image: Notice the URL and the ID of heading matches]

And here's how theskimm actually handles the request:[image: prettified from http://theskimm.com/assets/posts-de3b9b99ee4478aa9c2026c25fb31024.js]

Comment: Thanks for this. My issue is more with overriding the data shown on the thumbnail on Facebook / Twitter / LinkedIn. As you can see from this image [imgur](http://imgur.com/a/3Qd1J) they correctly pull the headline of that individual story and a short preview. When I share it only shows the title of the entire webpage.

Comment: Your page will need logic to then check for that query string and swap out the meta/OG tags accordingly.

Comment: how does one go about swapping out the meta/OG tags? that's the real issue I am having.